# css use different rem basis for an element

Tags: css

I have a section on my page that uses a third party stylesheet.
The stylesheet uses rem values and it was used on a page that uses a html font-size of 62.5%

However I have a fixed font-size of 14px on my html tag.

Can I somehow use a different basis for the rem values within the section?

```
<html style="font-size: 14px;">
<body>
    <div style="font-size: 1rem;">
        This content should be size 14px
    </div>
    <div class="wordpress">
        <div style="font-size: 1rem;">
            This content should be size 10px
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, of course you can’t, because `rem` _by definition_ refers to the font-size of the root element (which in HTML is the `html` element.)

Comment: No...`rem` is `root em` root is the base body / html font-size. Why not just use font-size and `em` for the extra class?

Comment: @Paulie_D The wordpress stylesheet uses a lot of rem values and the content section is much larger than just the one div

Comment: The only option would be to override the external stylesheet *after* it has loaded...and reset the `rem` value. I think....